# Bootstrap 4. Why not full width on mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Ok, so I'm ready to be laughed off SO for this question as I think I'm missing something very obvious but I'm tired, it's a Saturday and I'd rather not be working.

I'm just moving a project from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4. Can anyone tell me why the following code doesn't drop out to full screen on a mobile (xs) device?

It's pretty standard BS4

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

        <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                This is a test
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                This is a test  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have gutter both to the left and the right of the `.container` as shown here.

[image: Google Chrome Developer Tools mobile preview]

According to the docs this should work out of the box. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you will inspect the styles you will find container class looks like this

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

and the gutter you are getting are due margin-left auto and margin-right auto styles.

Comment: Yes, I could see that, I couldn't understand why. I came down to a missing <meta> hint tag for the viewport as none of my mobile related media queries were working.

Answer (score 0):

use container-fluid for full screen container

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

        <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                This is a test
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                This is a test  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explicitly show how by adding some code.